# PreparedStatement - Missing IN or OUT parameter at index - only if use clearParameters()

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, prepared-statement

I'm using Oracle 10; this is my code

```
String insertEntityItemQuery = " INSERT INTO My_schema.ENTITYITEM  (ENTITYITEMID, ENTITYID, FASCICOLOID, CALLERID, PARENTENTITYITEMID) " +
    " VALUES  ((My_schema.ENTITYITEMIDSequence.NEXTVAL), ? , ?, ?, ?) " ;


PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertEntityItemQuery , new String[]{"ENTITYITEMID"} ); 
preparedStatement.clearParameters();
preparedStatement.setInt(1, entityId);
preparedStatement.setString(2, fascicoloID);
preparedStatement.setString(3, callerID);
preparedStatement.setInt(4, parentEntityItemId);  
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

I get
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 5

but only if I use clearParameters() method, if I comment it the execution goes fine!!

It seems that clearParameters resets the My_schema.ENTITYITEMIDSequence.NEXTVAL
param, but how it is possible?

Comment: Which driver version?

Comment: JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver
JDBC driver version  : 10.2.0.2.0

Comment: It looks like the driver considers the generated keys column an OUT parameter and doesn't guard it when using `clearParameters()`. Have you tried a more recent JDBC driver version?

Comment: I haven't tried others drivers, but I think that a 10.2.x version shouldn't have this bug.... For now I solved by removing clearParameters() call, that is useless in this case